# How does WhenActivated actually work internally in ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am trying to understand how view activation/deactivation really works internally. These are some files I have been studying in the [ReactiveUI repo](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI):

- `ReactiveUI/Activation/ViewForMixins.cs`
- `ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/ReactiveUserControl.cs`
- `ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/ViewModelViewHost.cs`

If I understood it correctly, a view that has a `WhenActivated` block will get its activation instructions called as soon as it is instantiated. However, I cannot see when is the view deactivated (and by which mechanism), and then how the disposables defined in `WhenActivated` are disposed.

Comment: I'm not a user of this framework, but they describe that in manual (first page on github) with following `this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.SearchQuery, x => x.TextBox).DisposeWith(cleanup);`, where they are practically using `IDisposable pattern` + registering some method to be called during that. Whenever the view is closed - disposed, this should be called.

Comment: I made a video that went into this a little bit at reactiveUI conference if you look at the youtube channel for ReactiveUI. Look for the internals video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally we have a few different mechanisms.

First we have a `IActivationForViewFetcher` which gets registered with our Splat DI container. ReactiveUI then looks for registrations of the `IActivationForViewFetcher` and then determines from that if a activation/deactivate is needed. We generally use this approach when you have common base classes eg on WPF a `Control` which has lifetime events.

The other way is a View will derive off a `ICanActivate`, which as both Activated and Deactivated life times on it.

We use both these mechanisms to determine when to call `WhenActivated` which either the user registers the disposables they want to dispose as a `CompositeDisposable` or a `Func<IDisposable>` and register their disposable resources.

Then when we get a deactivated call, we will call `Dispose()` on those registered `IDisposable` objects.

WhenActivated is not the best name, because it handles the Activation, but also based on the registered IDisposable it can handle deactivation.